# why a database client software needs to connect to a server?

Tags: database

it may seem a rudimentary question , but i have been working with databases lately and i just don't understand why do the softwares (like mysql workbench or sql server) need to connect to a server ? and what is that server ? and what does it do?

why they don't work the same way as the IDE's work , i mean you write a program and you store it , and whenever you need it , you retrieve it from the hard disk or what ever else .

but a database client software needs to connect to a server and then you can create databases , save them and retrieve them .

what is the point of the the server? and why do we use the ip address 127.0.0.1 : 3306 to connect to it ( for example , when we are using sql , mysql )

i am sorry if the question sounds stupid :))

Comment: Well, apart from a bunch of other reasons, databases are typically used over network by many clients, therefore you cannot avoid having a server :) If you are looking for a serverless SQL DB to use locally, try out SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

The server is a software that manages the database, accepts SQL commands and return the results, it could have an UI but not only it would just complicate the development but would make it harder to enable its use in windowless environment, remember, not everybody uses microsoft windows, specially for servers.

Workbench is just a tool to create/edit/delete tables, rows, etc... it just makes it easy, otherwise you would to write SQL Commands to do all of those things, you can do that just now using the workbench or the MySQL command line.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-mysql-command-line-tool/

Side note, there are a lot of tools like workbench and most of them are a lot better and more intuitive, try it out:

http://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-workbench/